# Reading PHP as text

Tags: php

I know this sound silly, I would actually want to make PHP read another php file as text, because instead of opening the php in the editor I want, I want to display it using my browser and modify using JS. Here is what I have done:-

```
$code_to_display = "";
        echo "Language Found:".count($project_lang_file)."<br>";
            for ($x=0; $x < count($project_lang_file); $x++) {
                $code_to_display .= readfile($project_lang_file[$x]);
            //$code_to_display .= file_get_contents($project_lang_file[$x]);

        echo "Displaying code for $project_lang_file[$x] <br><br>";
            echo "<textarea id='myTextarea' style='color:black;'>$code_to_display</textarea><br>";
            }
```

I tried readfile, fopen, file_get_content, none actually display it as text. Anyone can help?

Comment: Use [highlight file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php) and it will even colour it in with syntax highlighting for you

Comment: @MarkBaker tried too... it shows empty as well... No idea why

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing a PHP File, with another php file, using Fwrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146626/editing-a-php-file-with-another-php-file-using-fwrite)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I have no idea why using file_get_content, fopen, readfile and other methods doesn't work. However, I found a way to solve it by duplicating the php and rename it as text file and it works perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
$code_to_display = "";
echo "Language Found:".count($project_lang_file)."<br>";
    foreach ($project_lang_file as $file) {
        if(file_exists($file)){
              $code_to_display = file_get_contents($file);

              echo "Displaying code for {$file} <br><br>";
              echo "<textarea id='myTextarea' style='color:black;'>{$code_to_display}</textarea><br>";
        } else {
              echo "File {$file} not exist"
        }
    }
```

Comment: As mentioned on my question, I tried fopen, file_get_content and readfile, none works.

Comment: Yes, but is not problem. it can heppents becouse path can be wrong, or becouse memory limit is exceeded (you concatanate each file content in loop). Also set E_ALL in your php.ini and write any error, or server response.

Comment: The condition is true, it goes through the "displaying code for", the result inside the textarea is empty.

Comment: but nvm, I think I managed to solved it already, thanks anyway. What I do now is duplicate the php as text file and display it on textarea.